# How to fit ms-sharepoint-ribbon to mobile view?

Tags: sharepoint

How to fit ms-sharepoint-ribbon's width (the black ribbon) to my design in mobile view, because it causes a white space at the left of the screen? please check the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to enable mobile view on SharePoint site collection which automatically changes your site layout to mobile friendly on mobile devices.

Some components like the content editor do not work on mobile views and if you need them, then I would suggest you to write your own CSS to hide the irrelevant icons from the ribbon and push then in a dropdown menu.

Comment: When I enable (Mobile Browser View) the ribbon successfully fits the mobile screen but the whole design disappeared :( until I switch to pc view.